# Why does SqlException over FK violation doesnt present the violated value?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2012

I am bulk inserting a long list of object. 
than i execute a commit.

It fails sometimes with the error (C#)

> `"The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint 
>   "FK_MyFK". The conflict occurred in database "DCDCommunity", table 
>   "MySchema.MyTable", column 'Id'.\r\nThe statement has been terminated."}
>
>   System.Exception {System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException}`

Now, do I have to write a program that iterates on my data files to find the value or can I get it in the exception?

Comment: RE: Question in the title the only people that can give you an official explanation are Microsoft. [Raise it on Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/Feedback) The unique constraint violation messages didn't tell you the offending value that raised the error until recent versions. I'd rather see the "string or binary data would be truncated" message improved first though.

Comment: As I remember this data is also not available in other DBs. I think it is part of the standards.

Answer (score 0):

I can't answer "why?" but I can offer a suggestion - do some pre-checks to your data before doing a bulk insert to make sure foreign keys are valid, and whatever other data issues you might *regularly* face - like checking string lengths to avoid the "string or binary data would be truncated" error as mentioned in a comment.

Comment: yes but making pre-checks takes time and is prone to a lot of errors. In a distributed system environment I will have to make sure the DB is locked during the checks and then insert my data. Then, the DB will do its own checks. which will probably be more thread/process safe and I could count only on those. I only need the  offending value